# maximum number of rules wso2 siddhi supported in siddhi server

Tags: wso2, siddhi

I was working with siddhi Complex Event Processor by running worker.sh and encountered that maximum number of rules that can be created in siddhi is 675. beyond which Post to /siddhi-apps is failing for creation of new rule. can you please let me how can this be enhanced to more than 1000.

Comment: If it's possible, can you please share a sample execution plan that you are trying to deploy, server-side exceptions if there's any, VM specs etc...?

Comment: Have u considered creating another duplicate execution plan and partitioning your input stream? Using storm you can distribute the execution plan on different nodes and even siddhi manager can support multiple query support.